# css dropdown menu dissappears when you try to select option

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, html-select, dropdown

have been trying to do a drop down menu; 
Problem is, when trying to hover over the options for the menu, the dropdown options disappear - BUT only sometimes! (other times, its fine!)

**Code:**

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  font-family: Arial;
  height: 60px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.container a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  height: 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

span {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 20px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  background-color: inherit;
}

.redhover a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: red;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a href="index.html"><img src="homeicon.jpg" width="50" alt="Home"></a>
  <div class="redhover">
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn">GCSEs</button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="chemistry.html">Chemistry</a>
        <a href="biology.html">Biology</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn">A-Levels</button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="chemistry.html">Chemistry</a>
        <a href="biology.html">Biology</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn">University</button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="chemistry.html">Telecommunications</a>
        <a href="biology.html">Electronic Engineering</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn">More</button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="biology.html">About me</a>
        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC5GPvJSUO4599z_ugFuoJwg">Youtube</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any ideas?

Many thanks,
Ryan

Comment: I think the problem is that there is too much spacing between the menu and the drop down list. Notice how if you hover over it fast enough, then it does work. Let me try and fix some of this for you.

Comment: Any chance you can post a working version of this on JSFiddle?

Answer (score 1):

Change .dropdown .dropbtn to padding: 18px 20px 19px 20px;
Because the padding is larger than your dropdown you will exit the hover area and the dropdown will close. See example for dropdown with smaller padding, so you wont exit the hover area

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  font-family: Arial;
  height: 60px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.container a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  height: 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

span {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 20px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 18px 20px 19px 20px;
  background-color: inherit;
}

.redhover a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: red;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a href="index.html"><img src="homeicon.jpg" width="50" alt="Home"></a>
  <div class="redhover">
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn">GCSEs</button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="chemistry.html">Chemistry</a>
        <a href="biology.html">Biology</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn">A-Levels</button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="chemistry.html">Chemistry</a>
        <a href="biology.html">Biology</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn">University</button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="chemistry.html">Telecommunications</a>
        <a href="biology.html">Electronic Engineering</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn">More</button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="biology.html">About me</a>
        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC5GPvJSUO4599z_ugFuoJwg">Youtube</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Exactly what I was going to say!

Comment: beat me to it ahaa

Comment: Awesome! Thank you. Im new to HTML and padding was causing me lots of problems as I was trying to get text to vertical-align (and image on left centrel) and it wasnt working, so centred it using padding. But it doesnt change too much and still looks okay. Any tips when using padding?

Comment: You shouldn't do this because it depends on the actual size of the font. In my browser, there's still a gap of 1px. See my answer for a better solution.

Comment: @RyanBrown by default the padding is added to the size of the box, so by giving the button 20px padding you will make the box 40px wider and higher. With the box-sizing property you can modify this behavior, for example if you set box-sizing: border-box the padding and border will be included in the height and width, and the box will not grow bigger than what you defined. See Aloso answer for a example.

Answer (score 1):

In your css remove the overflow: hidden;

```
.container {
  //delete overflow: hidden;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  font-family: Arial;
  height: 60px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  //delete overflow: hidden;
}
```

because it was overflowed, your dropdown menu hides the text. Delete the overflow in css, or create bigger boxes for dropdown menu.

Answer (score 1):

The black toolbar is `60px` high, but the buttons are slightly higher. Because of that, there's a small gap between the buttons and the dropdowns.

Adding

```
.dropdown .dropbtn {
  height: 60px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

adjusts the height of the buttons and fixes the problem:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  font-family: Arial;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 60px;
}

.container a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  height: 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

span {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 20px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  height: 60px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: inherit;
}

.redhover a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: red;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a href="index.html"><img src="homeicon.jpg" width="50" alt="Home"></a>
  <div class="redhover">
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn">GCSEs</button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="chemistry.html">Chemistry</a>
        <a href="biology.html">Biology</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn">A-Levels</button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="chemistry.html">Chemistry</a>
        <a href="biology.html">Biology</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn">University</button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="chemistry.html">Telecommunications</a>
        <a href="biology.html">Electronic Engineering</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn">More</button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="biology.html">About me</a>
        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC5GPvJSUO4599z_ugFuoJwg">Youtube</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome thanks - missed this answer the first time, not sure why!

Comment: I want to store my menu in a file called menu.html, and then just link it in on my other pages, rather than have menu code on each page. I dont suppose you would know how to achieve this?

Comment: With an iframe or with a server side language like php, Python or node.js

Comment: Do I have to change anything to use php coding in my html doc? If I renamed it as a php file, would it screw with any of my other html coding in the doc? Would I have to recode it all in php?

Comment: No, any HTML doc is also valid php. But you need a server that can run php code